# How to extract before "@" on email adress

Tags: dart

I'd like to extraxt string "test", which is the letters before "@",by using `RegExp` like following, but actually could get "test@" including "@".
How can I get only "test" without "@" ?

```dart
final getPass = "test@example.com";
final regEx = RegExp(r'(.+?)@');
print(regEx.firstMatch(getPass)?.group(0));
```

Comment: Have you tried `.group(1)`?

Comment: Use `[1]` instead of `.group(1)`. It's the same thing, and shorter.

Answer (score 2):

If using a `Regexp` is not mandatory for you, you could use `String` methods :

```
final getPass = "test@example.com";
print(getPass.split("@").first);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.group(1)`

```
final getPass = "test@example.com";
final regEx = RegExp(r'(.+?)@');
print(regEx.firstMatch(getPass)?.group(1));
```